# How can i disable access to a folder using htaccess without disallowing access to its files?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to disable access of a specific folder of my domain say: mydomain.com/newsletters/

BUT since i will be adding files inside /newsletters I want all files to be accessible.. say: mydomain.com/newsletters/april-newsletter.pdf

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can rewrite direct requests to the folder to an error handler / return an error code. See the documentation of the apache rewriting module for examples.

Comment: By “access”, you mean the directory listing the viewer would get?

Comment: Yes.. i dont want anyone will see the listing in that directory.. i just want the files inside that directory to be accessible if they have the link.